# Hibernate validator eats CPU on regex matching

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-validator

We are trying to validate address using hibernate validator. Some times hibernate validator hangs on java regex matching. It completed eats CPU usage and not able to process anything else. Is there any way to escape from this? Is this a bug in java 6??

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Character.codePointAt(Character.java:2335)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3344)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3737)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:3691)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4314)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4251)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1127)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.PatternValidator.isValid(PatternValidator.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.PatternValidator.isValid(PatternValidator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:114)
    at com.liquidation.unifiedregistration.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor440.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy76.validateUser(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's the regex and what input is it choking on? (You can check by catching the exception in a debugger and looking at the stack frame of `Matcher.matches()`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [High CPU usage in threads making calls to java.util.regex.Matcher:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767823/high-cpu-usage-in-threads-making-calls-to-java-util-regex-matcher)

Comment: This is very likely a case of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) which is unanswerable without knowing the actual regular expression. See also the question: [Regex gone wild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990609/regex-gone-wild-java-util-regex-pattern-matcher-goes-into-high-cpu-loop), which _was_ solved by examining the regex.